# array de controllers en php

Tags: php, array, router

Hola soy nuevo en esto y tengo un problema con mi archivo .php que la función de este archivo es tener un array de controllers y dependiendo el controlardor, realiza distintas acciones, mi problema es con el array, le paso código si me pueden ayudar, -gracias

```php
    <?php 
    $controllers=array(
    'Usuarios'=>['index','register','save','show','updateshow','update','delete','search','error','ingreso']
    'Roles'=>['index','register','save','show','updateshow','update','delete','error'] //aca error
    );
    if (array_key_exists($controller,  $controllers)) {
        if (in_array($action, $controllers[$controller])) {
            call($controller, $action);
        }
        else{
            call('Usuarios','error');
        }       
    }else{
        call('Usuarios','error');
    }
    function call($controller, $action){
        echo $controller ."--".$action;
        
        require_once('Controllers/'.$controller.'Controller.php');
        switch ($controller) {
            case 'Usuarios':
              require_once('Model/Usuarios.php');
              $controller= new UsuariosController();
            break;  
            case 'Roles':
              require_once('Model/Roles.php');
              $controller= new RolesController();
              break;    
                
            default:
                    # code...
            break;
        }
        
        $controller->{$action}();
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: El problema surge al querer agregar mas de un controlador en el array

Comment: Te falta una coma entre el elemento usuarios y el elemento roles dentro de tu array  `$controllers=array('Usuarios'=>['index','register','save','show','updateshow','update','delete','search','error','ingreso'],
'Roles'=>['index','register','save','show','updateshow','update','delete','error'] 
    );`

Comment: No me vas a creer que lo hice y me seguia dando error, ahora lo hice y no da error, eso que no cambie nada, muchas gracias

Comment: Como indico que me distes respuesta correcta?

Comment: Lo agrego como respuesta

Comment: Muchas Gracias Abraham Chan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lo que sucede es que hay un error de sintaxis en la forma en la que inicializas el arreglo.

La documentación de php da como ejemplo

```
$array = array(
    "foo" => "bar",
    "bar" => "foo",
);
```

Aquí puedes encontrar mas datos sobre esto [Arrays](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.types.array.php)

Revisando tu problema, te falta una coma entre el elemento usuarios y el elemento roles dentro de tu array. Tu código quedaría de la siguiente forma

```
 $controllers=array(
    'Usuarios' => ['index','register','save','show','updateshow','update','delete','search','error','ingreso'], 
    'Roles' => ['index','register','save','show','updateshow','update','delete','error'] 
 );
```